# where to use places API key?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, api-key

I need sample example in java script to places API.

I got the places API key from the below procedure.

Click the Services link from the left-hand menu.
Click the Status switch next to the Places API entry. The switch slides to On.
Click API access from the left navigation. Your key is listed in the Simple API Access section.

Any one please provide the sample code for places API?

Answer (score 4):

As described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/), the API key is passed as parameter (`key=AddYourOwnKeyHere`):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```